# Sending email with database content in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to send email in yii2. I store the body of my email in sqlyog. But, I have an error when I get information from database as the body of my email. The error is:

> quoted_printable_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given

. How can I solve it? This is my code:

```
$pesan = \frontend\models\Pesan::find()->select(['pesan'])->where(['kategori' => 'notifikasi_awal'])->one();
$message = $pesan;
$email = \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] => 'Sistem Informasi Paket'])
                ->setTo($tujuan)
                ->setSubject("[Pemberitahuan ]")
                ->setHtmlBody($message)
                ->send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instruction

```
$pesan = \frontend\models\Pesan::find()->select(['pesan'])
             ->where(['kategori' => 'notifikasi_awal'])->one();
```

return a model then an object

if you want a value you can obtain this value this way

```
$message = $pesan->your_message_field;
```